# how to get excel graphs to use the same custom date format as a cell mmm-yyyy

Tags: excel

I applied a custom date format to a column in excel (the format yyyy-mm e.g. 2014-01)

But when I create a graph out of three columns of data (date-in above format |heading|value) the graph shows the date as 2014-01-31 2014-02-28.

How do I get the graph to display the date as I have formatted it 2014-01 only without changing the data type to text and pasting values?

Comment: XL 2010 - and the chart is a line chart. What do you mean by linked axis to source. I have set the x axis - horizontal to the date but it's still showing as 2014-01-31 instead of 2014-01 yyyy-mm

Answer (score 0):

I use Excel 2013 but as far as I know this aspect of charting has not changed much since long before Excel 2010. Select your horizontal axis (click on one of the date labels in the chart), select Format Axis... and you should be able to:

(a) format the values there independently (ie in your case reapply the same custom format as applied to the raw data) and/or
(b) tick Linked to source.

The latter approach may not work quite as well as the former. Linked to source may mean something a little different from just "take the formatting from the raw data" (well, for the axis labels the format has to be common to all, whereas in the raw data it may differ between data points) and with a quick look I have not found details (for Excel 2010) of exactly what that is supposed to do.

So the former approach may be more reliable. For this you may need a two-step process. First make your custom format available to the chart and then apply it. That way the results are the same, chart and raw data formatting, though the process is not fully automatic.

One thing to watch out for is the linearity of the chart for time values. For example, if the dates are strings and the data points Jan 2012, Feb 2012 and March 2013 there is some risk the resulting labels will be *equally* spaced whereas the gap between the second two points should normally be thirteen times that of the gap between the first two points. Where data is approximately at regular time intervals anyway this is not always immediately obvious.